# How to run a python script from a text file context menu and compare it to other text files?

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd, contextmenu

I wrote a python script that takes two files as input and then saves the difference between them as output in another file.

I bound it to a batch file `.cmd` (see below) and added the batch file to context menu of text files, so when I right-click on a text file and select it, a `cmd` window pops up and I type the address of the file to compare.

Batch file content:

```
@echo off
cls
python "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Difference of Two Files.py" %1
```

Python Code:

```
import sys
import os

f1 = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
f1_name = str(os.path.basename(f1.name)).rsplit('.')[0]

f2_path = input('Enter the path of file to compare: ')
f2 = open(f2_path, 'r')
f2_name = str(os.path.basename(f2.name)).rsplit('.')[0]

f3 = open(f'{f1_name} - {f2_name} diff.txt', 'w')
file1 = set(f1.read().splitlines())
file2 = set(f2.read().splitlines())

difference = file1.difference(file2)

for i in difference:
    f3.write(i + '\n')

f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()
```

Now, my question is how can I replace the typing of 2nd file path with a drag and drop solution that accepts more than one file.

I don't have any problem with python code and can extend it myself to include more files. I just don't know how to edit the batch file so instead of taking just one file by typing the path, it takes several files by drag and drop.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: you cannot drag and drop multple onto the open cmd, but you can drag and drop to the batch file itself, where it exists as an icon. try this `echo "%~1" %~2" & pause` and drag 2 files to the icon where it exists.

Comment: When you drag and drop a file from Windows Explorer to the console, only one file drags, even if you have more than one file highlighted. This is built-in Windows behaviour and I think it might be rather difficult to change. What you *can* do is change your program to accept two files on a command line like this: `python "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Difference of Two Files.py" %1 %2`, drag the 2 files one at a time, and have your program issue the input statement only if it gets fewer than 2 files.

Comment: I'm aware of all of these. I can do this with creating a batch containing `%*` and simply drag all of the files and drop on it. But I want to right click on reference file and then drag and drop comparison files.

Comment: Using a GUI is also acceptable for me. I'm not restricting the solution to CMD. I just want a solution that I can drag and drop files on it. Doesn't matter how it would be done.

Comment: so you really want a way to identify the reference file so even if you have to drag 3 files to it, it will identify the reference and use the others as comparisons?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If we drag multiple files to a batch file, it will always recognize the first file as the reference file (due to the code). I want to separate reference file from the other ones.

Comment: and the reference file can be any file? or do you have something unique in the reference file name perhaps?

Comment: You could use `set /p file2="Enter filename"` in your batch and when it asks for a file name, drag and drop second file there and then press Enter. The path to the dragged file will be in variable `file2`

Comment: Yes. It can be any file. It doesn't have anything specific.

Comment: @montonero It already does this!

Comment: Where it does? As I can see it just run python script with one parameter. My suggestion is to add `set /p` before this and pass this new variable as a second parameter to script. This way you'll get your right-clicked file as `%1` and dragged one as `%file2%`

Comment: @montonero This is done by my python code: `f2_path = input('Enter the path of file to compare: ')`. It does the same thing that you suggested. Just the method differs.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I've missed the point. Then the only solution I see is a some GUI window which will accept dragged files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've figured it out myself!
I Post the final code, maybe it helps somebody.

```
# This script prints those lines in the 1st file that are not in the other added files
# and saves the results into a 3rd file on Desktop.

import sys
import os


f1 = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
f1_name = str(os.path.basename(f1.name)).rsplit('.')[0]
reference_set = set(f1.read().splitlines())

compare_files = input('Drag and drop files into this window to compare: ')
compare_files = compare_files.strip('"').rstrip('"')
compare_files_list = compare_files.split('\"\"')
compare_set = set()

for file in compare_files_list:
    with open(os.path.abspath(file), 'r') as f2:
        file_content = set(f2.read().splitlines())
    compare_set.update(file_content)


f3 = open(f'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\{f1_name} diff.txt', 'w')

difference = reference_set.difference(compare_set)

for i in difference:
    f3.write(i + '\n')

f1.close()
f3.close()
```

The idea came from this fact that drag and drop to `cmd`, copies the file path surrounded with double-quotes into it. I used the repeated double-quotes between paths to create a list, and you can see the rest in the code.
However, there's a downside and it's that you can't drag multiple files together and you should do that one by one, but it's better than nothing. ;)